# Program will not run while statements message

Tags: c++

I am making a game and I want it to only run if player consents by saying PLAY but it won't run. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int balance = 500;
    char start;

    cout << "Welcome to Vegas! Your starting balance is 500 dollars lets play! " << endl;
    cout << "Type PLAY to begin !" <<endl;
    cin >> start;
    while(start == 'PLAY') {

        cout << "Your beginning numbers are!" << endl;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`start` is a char and not an array of char. You are only storing one letter in `start` 
Change that, and also change `'PLAY'` to `"PLAY"`. Consider using a `std::string` instead.

Example of what you can do:

```
int balance = 500;
char start[256];
bool started = false;

cout << "Welcome to Vegas! Your starting balance is 500 dollars lets play! " << endl;
cout << "Type PLAY to begin !" <<endl;
cin >> start;

if (!strcmp(start, "PLAY")) {  // #include <cstring>
    started = true;
}

while(started) {
    cout << "Your beginning numbers are!" << endl;
}
```

Or with using `std::string`:

```
int balance = 500;
string start;
bool started = false;

cout << "Welcome to Vegas! Your starting balance is 500 dollars lets play! " << endl;
cout << "Type PLAY to begin !" <<endl;
cin >> start;

if (start == "PLAY") {
    started = true;
}

while(started) {
    cout << "Your beginning numbers are!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is a single character, like `'P'`. If you expect the user to enter a full *string*, you want to use `std::string`. Additionally, you probably want to simply check *if* the user entered the string you wanted - not *while* - unless you want to prompt again at the end of your game.

Corrected code would be:

```
std::string start;
// ...
std::cin >> start;
if (start == "PLAY") {
    // play the game
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `char start;` to `char start[100];`

and `while(start == 'PLAY')` to `while(start == 'PLAY')`

Here is the final code

```
int balance = 500;
char start[100];

cout << "Welcome to Vegas! Your starting balance is 500 dollars lets play! "<< endl;
cout << "Type PLAY to begin !" <<endl;
cin >> start;
while(!strcmp(start,"PLAY")) {

    cout << "Your beginning numbers are!" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take in as input a string, but storing using a character.
use
char start[SIZE];

Also are u sure comparing with 'PLAY' is being done in the right way? Use " for strings. Better to use string functions.